# How to stop jQuery jumping to the link I just called using .trigger()

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I'm using jQuery and have three elements on my page:

- a list of search results (businesses)
- a Bootstrap modal
- a Google map

For each business in the list of search results, there's a button that when clicked on loads some content into the Bootstrap modal customised to that particular business and then opens it.

At the top of the page there's also a Google map that displays markers for each of the businesses. When these markers are clicked on, the same action should be carried out as for each button in the list i.e. load some content into the Bootstrap modal and then open it.

I'm using the .trigger() event handler to simulate a click on the button in the list when the associated marker for that business is clicked on in the Google map. This works fine but what happens is that when the Bootstrap modal is closed, the browser window scrolls down to where the button that .trigger() was called on is rather than staying in the position that it was originally in when the action was called. The effect is that every time you click on a different marker, open the Bootstrap modal and then close it, you end up jumping to a different position on the page.

The code I use in my Google Maps marker callback looks like this:

```
function marker_callback() {
    var selected_marker = this;
    $('#' + selected_marker.id).trigger('click');
}
```

When the click event is called, it then calls this code:

```
$('body').on('click', '.view_profile', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    // AJAX code goes here, and if successful it runs the next line
    $('#my_modal').show();
});
```

I'm not sure if it's jQuery or Bootstrap that's shifting the browser window to where it thinks the button was last clicked. If I open the Bootstrap modal and use the cursor keys to move up or down the page, when I close it the browser window still jumps back to where the button is.

Thank you in advance for any comments or suggestions.

Comment: What if you make the function its own named function, and then just call that named function in the `click` handler and wherever else you need to call it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this code in bootstrap.js file (if you use newest version 3.3.5):

```
$target.one('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  $this.is(':visible') && $this.trigger('focus')
})
```

This above code focuses on button when modal is hidden.

You can use something like this:

```
$('#my_modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
  $('.open-modal').trigger();
});
```

`.open-modal` refers to button in the list of search results, so change this to your CSS class.

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGJZmL)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I couldn't get this working, but what I've done is copied the code from the button action into the marker callback function and am now calling $('#my_modal').modal('toggle'); at the start of the marker callback function. This opens the modal window correctly and when the modal window is closed the position on the page doesn't change.